# OpenCV algorithm of contours searching and creation of bounding rectagle

Tags: python, algorithm, opencv, computer-vision, contour

Hi to the whole programmers society!

It has become habitual to me to get acknowledgement of every algorithm I employ in projects. And not long ago I implemented OpenCV library methods to detect contours within input frame as well as to draw bounding rectangle around detected object. So I came up with question: what algorithm is actually used by OpenCV when calling appropriate methods? (I mean exacty cv2.findContours and cv2.boundingRect methods)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to OpenCV documentation [findContours](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours) uses "[Suzuki, S. and Abe, K., Topological Structural Analysis of Digitized Binary Images by Border Following](http://tcc-neto.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Artigos%20para%20revis%C3%A3o%20bibliogr%C3%A1fica/Topological%20%20Structural%20%20Analysis%20%20of%20%20Digitized%20%20Binary.pdf)"

> The function retrieves contours from the binary image using the algorithm [Suzuki85].

I didn't find description of boundingRect algorithm but found [this file in opencv repo](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/7d4d28605087ec2d3878f9467aea313a2acdfd49/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contour_features/py_contour_features.markdown)

> 7.a. Straight Bounding Rectangle
>   It is a straight rectangle, it doesn't consider the rotation of the object. So area of the bounding rectangle won't be minimum. It is found by the function cv2.boundingRect().
>   Let (x,y) be the top-left coordinate of the rectangle and (w,h) be its width and height. @code{.py} x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt) cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2) @endcode

So it seems that boundingRect just finds minimum and maximum coordinates of input set of points

PS Sorry for my poor English